# Remote database not connecting with Java app

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, mariadb

I have a java project and for that, I needed a remote database, I purchased a aws instance for public IP, installed MySql with PhpMyAdmin but the database is not connecting with the project via my public IP but if I use a ngrok port forward then it is connecting with the database, and the error its producting is:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
```

please help!!

[Working with Ngrok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jNvB.png)

[Not working with public ip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQzPZ.png)

Comment: Understand the concepts of network and ip addresses, your instance public IP isn't going to serve your db unless you open port via firewall, which you shouldn't do in first place for security reasons. Also if database is in same machine, you can simply use localhost or 127.0.0.1 as your ip address. If not we will need more information on the topic.

Comment: Just to be clear, you can use phpMyAdmin to manually perform some administrative tasks on your database, but your Java project will directly connect to the database (or much, much better, to an API endpoint you write that lives on the server); phpMyAdmin isn't the interface for your application to connect to. It seems you're already okay on that understanding, but for others who may have similar problems it important to realize that phpMyAdmin isn't an API for external applications.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the database has a public endpoint (ping it for instance in order to see that it has a public address). Then just check security group permissions.